# Google Cloud Platform: Minimal IAM permissions for gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to find in the official GCP documentation the exact permission (not Role) that corresponds to the ability to invoke this command

```
gcloud container clusters resize
```

The [list](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) does not include such a permission.

Any suggestion about the least privilege that needs to be granted for such an operation?

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud container clusters resize` operation probably needs the caller to have `container.clusters.update` permission. You can find this permission in the following predefined roles :

- Kubernetes Engine Admin (`roles/container.admin`)
- Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin (`roles/container.clusterAdmin`)

See [Kubernetes Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles). I have not listed other roles containing this permission because they are too broad (`roles/owner`, `roles/editor`) or not appropriate (`roles/composer.worker`).

Based on the principle of least privilege and if you want to keep things simple using predefined roles, your user only needs to be granted `roles/container.clusterAdmin` because `roles/container.clusterAdmin` role contains a subset of `roles/container.admin` permissions.

Additionally, if you want/need to be more restrictive, you could also create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#custom_roles) with only the permission you need.

Comment: Yes that's what I want (to create a custom role) but I cannot assign (**just**) this permission because it does not exist! (or it exists in a misleading context, the `update`)

Comment: @pkaramol - some permissions are hard to find in the console using the search filters. Use the CLI to create custom roles. `gcloud iam roles create`. To view what permissions another role has to get the exact spelling use `gcloud iam roles describe`.

Comment: Indeed, the `resize` permission does not exist. I believe the only way is to grant the `container.clusters.update` permission, which (sadly in your case) also allows to update other parameters. Ideally, there should be an IAM permission allowing only to call [`setSize`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters.nodePools/setSize) method on a node pool (that's what `gcloud container clusters resize` does), but unfortunately it does not exist yet.